# Make a parameter subsitution in bash aliases for ssh

Tags: bash

Is there a way I can create a alias for this command and have it ask for the host.

`ssh -i .ssh/name.pem root@`

Thx

Comment: You'll need to define a function instead of an alias.

Comment: "Ask", meaning prompt? And why do you want to use an alias, as opposed to a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following should work (not tested)

```
sshfunction(){
  echo "Specify your hostname:"
  read host
  ssh -i .ssh/name.pem root@"$host"
}
```

Then:

```
$ sshfunction
```

Though if it was me, I'd just provide the hostname as a variable and cut-out the middle man.

---

Better yet, populate your `~/.ssh/config` file (if it doesn't exist you can just create it):

```
host MyHostName
        Hostname 123.456.7.89
        User username
```

Then:

```
$ ssh MyHostName
```

Comment: You can go one further as well if you are hell-bent on using an alias. Once you enter a host into the `config` file, you can alias that. Useful if you're providing other options like `-X`, `-Y`. E.g. `alias connect='ssh -X root@MyHostName'`. But obviously this circles back to the original problem that you need functions instead of aliases if you want to give it input.